boot issues on kernel 6.5.0.34 in ubuntu 22.04
the most recent kernel version, I have got from canonical is 6.5.0.34. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on an AMD A6-9225 RADEON R4 laptop.
My problem: my machine does not boot any more. it stucks at the initramfs message. I tried to repair my grub installation/configuration and reinstalling the kernel. No success.
Can someone help me with this issue? I cannot find any information regarding this problem, and there are no messages logged to any of the system protocols.
Booting from an older kernel succeeds.
Thank in advance...
